# Deserialize JSON to Java using Jackson 2

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON:

```
{"evaluationPart": {
    "generatedId": "48D5181DB8704F8AB5FC998964AD9075",
    "evaluationQuestionPartOption": {
        "generatedId": "48D5181DB8704F8AB5FC998964AD9075"
    }
}}
```

I've created java classes for it to represent it:

The root class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"evaluationPart"})
public class JsonEvaluationPart {

    @JsonProperty("generatedId")
    private String generatedId;

    @JsonProperty("evaluationQuestionPartOption")
    private JsonQuestionOption questionOption;

    public String getGeneratedId() {
        return generatedId;
    }

    public void setGeneratedId(String generatedId) {
        this.generatedId = generatedId;
    }

    public JsonQuestionOption getQuestionOption() {
        return questionOption;
    }

    public void setQuestionOption(JsonQuestionOption questionOption) {
        this.questionOption = questionOption;
    }
}
```

And the `JsonQuestionOption` class:

```
public class JsonQuestionOption {

    @JsonProperty("generatedId")
    private String generatedId;

    public String getGeneratedId() {
        return generatedId;
    }

    public void setGeneratedId(String generatedId) {
        this.generatedId = generatedId;
    }
}
```

I have written a small JUnit test to check how it goes:

```
public class JsonReaderTest {

    /**
     * Logger for this class.
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonReaderTest.class);

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private static final String JSON = "{\"evaluationPart\": {\n" +
            "    \"generatedId\": \"48D5181DB8704F8AB5FC998964AD9075\",\n" +
            "    \"evaluationQuestionPartOption\": {\n" +
            "        \"generatedId\": \"48D5181DB8704F8AB5FC998964AD9075\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}}";

    @Before
    public void setUp()
            throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("Creating the object mapper.");
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        LOGGER.debug("Object mapper successfully created. {}", objectMapper);
    }

    @Test
    public void testJsonReader()
            throws Exception {

        JsonEvaluationPart partType = objectMapper.readValue(JSON, JsonEvaluationPart.class);
        assertNotNull(partType);

        LOGGER.debug("Part: {}.", partType);

        assertEquals(partType.getGeneratedId(), "48D5181DB8704F8AB5FC998964AD9075");
        assertEquals(partType.getQuestionOption().getGeneratedId(), "48D5181DB8704F8AB5FC998964AD9075");
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I am reading my JSON like this:

```
JsonEvaluationPart partType = objectMapper.readValue(JSON, JsonEvaluationPart.class);
```

All the properties in `partType` are `null`. What I am doing wrong here and how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [JsonIgnoreProperties](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) means:

```
Annotation that can be used to either suppress serialization of properties 
(during serialization), or ignore processing of JSON properties read (during 
deserialization).
```

Just try replacing:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"evaluationPart"})
```

with:

```
@JsonTypeName("evaluationPart")
```

Comment: If I change it I am getting this exception:

Then I am getting this exception: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "evaluationPart" (class com.company.core.json.JsonEvaluationPart), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: , "generatedId", "evaluationQuestionPartOption"])`

Comment: That's because of JSON / model. Just create a class like ``public class JsonEvaluationPartWrapper { private JsonEvaluationPart jep; }``: that's what your JSON actually corresponds to!

Answer (score 0):

Your Json Headers is wrong. 
use

```
@JsonTypeName("evaluationPart")
```

instead of

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"evaluationPart"})
```

Comment: Then I am getting this exception: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "evaluationPart" (class com.company.core.json.JsonEvaluationPart), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: , "generatedId", "evaluationQuestionPartOption"])`

Comment: Do you know what might cause this exception?

Comment: Your Json is notstandard. Use "{\n" +
            "    \"generatedId\": \"48D5181DB8704F8AB5FC998964AD9075\",\n" +
            "    \"evaluationQuestionPartOption\": {\n" +
            "        \"generatedId\": \"48D5181DB8704F8AB5FC998964AD9075\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}"